# link group color thanks to mapper to shiny

Tags: r, loops, shiny, mapper, topology

I am developing a topological data analysis app on R thanks to shiny and I have some trouble with one of my functions.

I would like to put those lines into the server as reactive elements:

```
l = length(V(aspargus.graph))

cc.maj.vertex <- c()
filter.vertex <- c()
for (i in 1:l){
  points.in.vertex <- aspargus.mapper$points_in_vertex[[i]]
  Mode.in.vertex <- Mode(normaspargus$`DataAspargus$Treatment`[points.in.vertex])
  cc.maj.vertex <- c(cc.maj.vertex,as.character(Mode.in.vertex))
  filter.vertex <- c(filter.vertex,mean(filter_list[points.in.vertex]))
}


vertex.size <- rep(0,l)
for (i in 1:l){
  points.in.vertex <- aspargus.mapper$points_in_vertex[[i]]
  vertex.size[i] <- length((aspargus.mapper$points_in_vertex[[i]]))
}
MapperNodes <- mapperVertices(aspargus.mapper, labels_pts )
MapperNodes$cc.maj.vertex <- as.factor(cc.maj.vertex)
MapperNodes$filter_list <- filter.vertex
MapperNodes$Nodesize <- vertex.size

MapperLinks <- mapperEdges(aspargus.mapper)
```

My main problems are for the for loop (lines 5 and 14), and the column change as:

```
MapperNodes$filter_list <- filter.vertex
```

At the moment my code looks like that:

```
server <- function (input, output){
  l = reactive({length(V(data.mapper.graph()))})
  
  reactive({for (i in 1:l()){
   points.in.vertex <- reactive({data.mapper()$points_in_vertex[[i]]})
   Mode.in.vertex <- reactive({Mode(X1()$`DataAspargus$Treatment`[points.in.vertex()])})
   cc.maj.vertex <- reactive({c(cc.maj.vertex(),as.character(Mode.in.vertex()))})
   filter.vertex <- reactive({c(filter.vertex(),mean(f()[points.in.vertex()]))})
  }
  })
  
  
  vertex.size <- reactive({rep(0,l)})
  reactive({for (i in 1:l){
    points.in.vertex <- reactive({data.mapper()$points_in_vertex[[i]]})
    vertex.size()[i] <- reactive({length((data.mapper()$points_in_vertex[[i]]))})
 }
 })
  
 MapperNodes <- reactive({mapperVertices(data.mapper(), labels_pts )})
 MapperNodes$cc.maj.vertex <- reactive({as.factor(cc.maj.vertex())})
 MapperNodes$f <- reactive({filter.vertex()})
 MapperNodes$Nodesize <- reactive({vertex.size()})
 
 MapperLinks <- reactive({mapperEdges(data.mapper())})
```

As you can imagine, it is not working:

```
Error in MapperNodes$cc.maj.vertex <- reactive({ : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I have tried to put bracket before MapperNodes, after etc...and I don't find any solution...

I hope someone will get an idea!
If you need any more details, feel free to ask :D

Comment: Could you please include in your question how it connects to [`topology`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology)?

Comment: Mapper is a #tolopoly function, the goal here is to display a topological data analysis graph coloured by groups.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve this problem is to put all the code inside the output function.